# Can't access or index into Python DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe

I am a noob to Python, but this seems simple enough based on all the Google searches I've done, yet I still get an error.  All I'd like to do is access the row named 'Ebit' in the DataFrame, yet I get this AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Ebit'

Ebit is clearly a name in the index, but I've tried numerous methods and assume I'm missing something simple?

Any help would be appreciated!

Here is the code:

```
import yfinance as yf
DHR = yf.Ticker("DHR")
dhrQtrFin = DHR.quarterly_financials
Ebit = dhrQtrFin.Ebit
```

Comment: `dhrQrtFin.Ebit` is accessing a column named `Ebit`, not a row.

Comment: How do I access the row named Ebit?  I was following examples and thought that was correct?

Comment: I think it's `dhrQtrFin.loc['Ebit']` but I'm not a pandas expert

Comment: That worked - thank you!  Could have sworn I tried that, but maybe I forgot the .loc before ['Ebit'].  Super helpful!